# How to check username and password from database in yii 1.1.13

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am very new to `Yii`.
 Now i had installed yii 1.1.13 version in Xampp server. I can view the "My Web Application" Page.

In there, I can view the login form. Now, I want to login with the help of my username and password, which is stored in database. How could I done that. 
I checked some tutorials, but I can't get clear idea. Please anybody explain about that.

[image: My Screenshot of the web page.]

Comment: Hi Jebil, can you please show what you have tried yet? Better chances of getting good answers on that, as of now, this may generate opinionated answers. Do read our [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't

Comment: Formatted post + removed thanks

Comment: I had changed my database name in main.php which is under protected/config folder. I need to check username and password from my database. But i don't know how. I think i need to do in useridentity.php file which is under protected/components folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a table in your database which stores user and password data, for example `User` and a model corresponding to this table. Model file is stored by default in `protected/models`.

As you mentioned, you heed to have a `UserIdentity` class. Place it in `protected/components`. This method should have private `$_id` variable, getter for this variable and `authenticate` method, which is responsible for authentication. Check this:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
        if($record===null)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if($record->password!==md5($this->password))
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else
        {
            $this->_id=$record->id;
            $this->setState('title', $record->title);
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

So what happens in `authenticate` method? You search a record from `User` table and assign it to variable. If record not found, then add error that username is invalid. Next element of `if..elseif..else` statement comparing passwords: if password from DB is not equal than hashed by md5 function of entered password, then add error - wrong password. (Remember that you need to store md5-hashed passwords in DB in this case!) If there are not errors - user entered correct data and you can set id and some session information.

I think if you modify your code with that, you will be able to use authentice with DB-stored data.